# Raspberry pi stuck at smbd.service?

Tags: boot, bash, raspberry-pi-os, interrupts

I edited my /home/pi/.bashrc file, and i reboot it, but the raspberry pi stuck at smbd.service with the welcome screen.

Comment: what could you have possibly put in `/home/pi/.bashrc` that is at all related to anything in the boot process - please share what you did to that file

Comment: Actually there I put my custom python application command like " sudo ./filename".

Comment: remove it, see if that helps, if it doesn't, it's probably something else you did

Comment: But I can't, because when I powering my raspberry, they stuck at welcome screen. And also I tryout some terminal exit methods, that's not working.

Comment: add `init=/bin/sh` to `cmdline.txt` - if even this doesn't work, then you've done something else to the pi that you haven't mentioned - restore from your most recent working backup, then be careful with what you do

Comment: But the raspberry pi in console window right now, I can't able to change the settings

Comment: you know you can edit cmdlint.txt in **another computer** ... right? Of course, if you're running NOOBS, just cut your losses and start from scratch

Comment: `.bashrc` is **NOT** intended to run scripts.

It is run each time a non-login interactive shell is started and is used to configure the shell.  
`~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells`.

Comment: Yes, But how can I change the settings.

Answer (score 1):

First do what @Milliways wrote in his answer.

You are then in a command line shell where you type the following commands:

```
mv /home/pi/.bashrc /home/pi/bashrc.broken
mv /root/.bashrc /root/bashrc.broken
```

Then remove the `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` and reboot.

Comment: Actually my window in auto login CLI mode, so when I power on the raspberry pi,The welcome screen stuck at smbd.service and then I press F2 the custom application error is displaying continuously,I can't able to exit from this error and modify anything.

Comment: Then you didn't append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt`. as Milliways instructed.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to restore from your backup.

If your Pi won't boot you can repair by rebooting to a root shell.

1. Append `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt` (which can be done on any computer) and reboot.
2. After booting you will be at the prompt in a root shell.
3. Your root file system is mounted as readonly now, so remount it as read/write `mount -n -o remount,rw /`

Comment: That's not working, Now I gonna start from scratch.